# proving $\int_{0}^{1}f=A$ when $f:\left [ 0,1 \right ] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

Given $f:\left [ 0,1 \right ] \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ integrable function, and $\lim_{t\rightarrow 1^-}\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(t^n)(t^n-t^{n+1})=A$,

exists and is finite.

Need to prove: $\int_{0}^{1}f=A$.

Any help?

Comment: Maybe you mean $f(t^n)(t^n-t^{n+1})$?

Comment: yes, you are right it's a typo.

Comment: In that case it can be done. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Note the assumptions carefully. In addition to assuming that $f$ is (presumably) Riemann integrable, it is assumed that 
$s_t = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(t^n)(t^n-t^{n+1})$ exists for all $t$ sufficiently close to one, and that
$\lim_{t\uparrow 1} s_t=A$.

We want to show that $A= \int_0^1 f$.

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded, say $|f(t)| \le M$.

Let $t \in (0,1)$ and $P_{N,t}$ be the partition $(0,t^{N+1},t^N,t^{N-1},...,t^2,t,1)$. It is easy to see that
$\operatorname{mesh} P_{n,t} = \max(1-t,t^{N+1})$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, then since $f$ is Riemann integrable there exists some $\delta$ such that if $\operatorname{mesh} P< \delta$, then
$U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$ (and we have $L(f,P) \le \int_0^1 f \le U(f,P)$, of course).

Choose $t',N'$ such that $\operatorname{mesh} P_{N,t} <\delta$ whenever $N \ge N', t \in (t',1)$.

Note that $L(f,P_{N,t}) \le f(t^{N+1}) t^{N+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(t^n)(t^n-t^{n+1}) +f(1) (1-t)\le U(f,P_{N,t})$, and so we have
$|f(t^{N+1}) t^{N+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}f(t^n)(t^n-t^{n+1}) +f(1)(1-t)- \int_0^1 f | < \epsilon$. Taking the limit as $N \to \infty$ (and remembering that $|f(t^{N+1}) t^{N+1}| \le M t^{N+1} \to 0$) gives
$|s_t+f(1)(1-t)-\int_0^1 f| \le \epsilon$.

Now taking the limit as $t \uparrow 1$ gives $|A-\int_0^1 f| \le \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

For each $t$, the sum is a Riemann sum. It estimates $\int_{t^{N+1}}^t f(x) dx$ using the right endpoint of each rectangle. Assuming $f$ is Riemann integrable, the sum will converge to $\int_0^t f(x) dx$ as $N \to \infty$.  So it is enough to show that $\lim_{t \to 1^-} \int_0^t f(x) dx = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$. This follows from the fact that indefinite integrals are continuous, which follows from the fact that they are differentiable, which follows from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

There is a technicality that I skipped here. The left endpoint of the Riemann sums is not constant in this problem, which means you technically cannot use the usual result about Riemann integration directly. But you can write:

\begin{eqnarray*}
& &\left | \sum_{n=1}^N f(t^n) \left ( t^n - t^{n+1} \right ) - \int_0^t f(x) dx \right |  \\
& \leq & \left | \sum_{n=1}^N f(t^n) \left ( t^n - t^{n+1} \right ) - \int_{t^{N+1}}^t f(x) dx \right | + \left | \int_0^{t^{N+1}} f(x) dx \right |
\end{eqnarray*}

Then the first term goes to zero by the usual result, and you can argue separately that the last term goes to zero.

Comment: In the first line, what sum are you talking about? There is no Riemann sum mentioned in the question.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^N f(t^n) \left ( t^n - t^{n+1} \right )$ is a Riemann sum. Rather, it's "essentially" a Riemann sum, modulo the fact that the left endpoint depends on $N$.

Comment: It cannot be the case that the first sum mentioned converges to $\int_0^t f$. For a fixed $t$, the sum 'ignores' the values of $f$ on (say) $(t^2,t)$, regardless of $n$. What I am saying is that you could modify $f$ on $(t^2,t)$ and the limit will be the same even though the integral may be different.

Comment: You are right, this problem is more delicate than I realized. In the $C^1$ case I would probably proceed by using the error estimate for the rectangle rule to get an estimate for $|S_N(t) - \int_0^t f(x) dx|$. I see that in the general case you have to proceed as you've described, finding a good enough $N$ for the inner limit and then defining your good enough $t$ in terms of $N$ and $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Yeah, the iterated limits add an interesting twist.

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the Riemann integral, we need a partition sequence $\Delta_k=\{0=x_{0}<x_1<x_2<\ldots <x_{n_k}=1\}$ with $\limsup_{k\to\infty}|x_{j_k}-x_{(j-1)_k}|\to 0$ and then the integral is

$$\int_0^1f=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}f(x_{i_k})(x_{i_k}-x_{(i-1)_k})$$

Fix $0<t<1$ and let $\Delta_N=\{0=x_0, t^N, t^{N-1},\ldots ,t^2, t, t^0=1\}$. Clearly this is listed in ascending order.

Then noting that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|t^{n}-t^{n+1}|\le t$ for $n>0$ we see that as $N\to\infty$ that

$$f(1)(1-t)+\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N}f(t^n)(t^{n}-t^{n+1})+f(t^N)(t^N-0)\right)\approx \int_0^1f$$

The last term individually goes to $0$ since $f$ is bounded and $t^N\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Letting $t\to 1^-$ we get the size of the mesh going to $0$ and the first term going to $0$ because $f$ is bounded, and we achieve equality.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that the last limit converges to the integral. By assumption it converges, but not necessarily to the integral. Otherwise you could fix $t= {1 \over 2}$ (say) and then the sum would ignore whatever $f$ does on the interval $(t,1)$.

Comment: @copper.hat Oops, forgot $n=0$, I knew something felt off. I'll fix that, and thanks!

Comment: The statement is still not true. The left hand side approximates the integral, but is not (necessarily) equal to it.